# CSS usage of @include in this example? Can I replace them with @import?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-deployment

I'm using a template from a GitHub project: https://github.com/network-automation/ansible_inventory_report/blob/master/css/main.css

In the example, it uses @include in a lot of places, but not @import.

I'm new to CSS and I can't contact the owner. After searching, there's actually no specific definition and sample code of @include tag for CSS.

What does @include do and why it is not @import? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: @Chris G: How disappointing. That question has a title alluding to the misleading .css extension that's also seen here, but the answer doesn't so much as address it.

Comment: @BoltClock I do in fact always check the other question before marking it as dupe, and it makes perfectly clear that `@include` isn't a part of CSS, which implicitly means it's not interchangeable with `@import`, a directive that does something entirely different.

Comment: @Chris G: But it does not clarify what an SCSS directive is doing in a .css file, or why some SCSS stylesheets are given the .css extension and masquerading as compiled CSS files in general. That just seems unnecessarily confusing to new developers.

Comment: @BoltClock Let's agree to disagree. If a beginner cannot be bothered to google SCSS and this is fine with you, who am I to object?

Comment: @Chris G: It would be much easier for someone to google SCSS had the file been called scss/main.scss and not css/main.css in the first place. The top SCSS-related result for "css @include" is the duplicate question, which again makes no acknowledgement of the naming confusion, and even if some readers are content with learning that Sass is a thing, I personally still can't rationalize intentionally mislabeling non-CSS files as CSS. But yes, I'm fine with disagreeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no @include in **CSS**.

@include is used by **SASS** ( to include mixins )

By the way **SASS** is an extension of **CSS** which makes **CSS styling** much easier.

**SASS** files can end with **.sass** or **.scss**

https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. Just mark them and move on.

Comment: I didn't see the author uses @minxin at all, or in any other file. Is it a slip or on purpose?

Comment: @user6219476 there are many other mistakes. This main.css file he uploaded isn't css and the mixins are obviously missing. Clearly an error from the author.

Comment: Thanks, a @include tag with no mixin means nothing is happening?

Comment: The github project is intended to be used as extension for something called RedHat Ansible. It can be assumed that the project doesn't have tons of errors but rather will work fine, just not on its own.

Comment: @user6219476 https://hastebin.com/odakiqaxug.css try this css instead.